# Mouse does not interact with XFCE

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, mouse

I run XFCE 4.10 in Archlinux and I have had my mouse (and/or XFCE) behaving weirdly for a couple of days.

The mouse works fine when I first start XFCE. I can interact normally with UI features. However, when I launch an application (i.e. Firefox), the mouse pointer will stop to interact with the UI elements of XFCE although it still works within the application. For example, I can click on bookmarks and the navigation buttons of Firefox, but clicking on the panels and the window frame buttons will not be registered until I close the application with Alt-F4.

If I close Firefox and restart it, the mouse even refuses to work within Firefox. Unplugging and replugging it makes it interact again with Firefox but not with XFCE. However, if I completely unplug the mouse, I can use the trackpad successfully both in XFCE and in Firefox!

Note that I used Firefox as an example. Same issue with Thunderbird, urxvtc, etc. May it be some issue with the drivers? Note that (re)installing xf86-input-mouse does NOT solve the issue.

I think it may be be some issue related to how XFCE deals with focus and mouse input, but I have no idea where to look. I have looked around in the forums but I could not find any related issues. Could anybody help me see where to start troubleshooting? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, my totally tech-naive partner solved the issue by changing the mouse. I still cannot fathom how the old mouse worked selectively in applications and stopped to work in the desktop environment, but here we go.